# Extract from table (Scrapy)

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

want to ask for a help with table parsing using scrapy in python2
Here is my table:
[link to table](https://pastebin.com/abaYzcn0)
I need to get values of the `<td>` tags.
Try to use next python code:

```
rows = resp.xpath('//*[@id="Vorlage_Infobox_Unternehmen"]')
if not rows:
    rows = resp.xpath('.//*[@id="Vorlage_Infobox_Unternehmen"]//table')
try:
    if rows:
        extract = lambda row, path: row.xpath(path).extract_first().strip()
        if '<th>' in str(rows):
            infobox = {extract(row, 'string(./th)'): extract(row, 'string(./td)') for row in rows}
        elif '<tr>' in str(rows):
            infobox = {extract(row, 'string(./td[1])'): extract(row, 'string(./td[2])') for row in rows}
        elif '<table>' in str(rows):
            infobox = {extract(row, 'string(./th)'): extract(row, 'string(./td)') for row in rows}
        else:
            infobox = {extract(row, 'string(./table/tbody/tr[1])'): extract(row, 'string(./td[1])') for row in rows}
```

But I do something wrong and can not get what I wand. Please help me to understand my mistake.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you specify expected result

Comment: Why don't you use a row selector and then parse every row and add the values to the infobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the values of `<td>` inside `<table>` you could do this on your xpath:

```
    table = resp.xpath('//table[@id="Vorlage_Infobox_Unternehmen"]')
    if table:
        all_table_data = table.xpath('//td')
```

when you use `table.xpath('some_xpath')` it will apply it on the element that was already selected. You could also skip that test and do it directly:

```
    all_table_data = resp.xpath('//table[@id="Vorlage_Infobox_Unternehmen"]//td')
```